# Reduce time precision in a time series to minutes from seconds

Tags: r, xts

I have financial time series data with the following date Format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  I am trying to reduce its time precision to minutes instead of seconds efficiently.

Sample Data:

```
  dd <- c("2014-02-23","2014-03-12", "2014-05-29")
    tt <- c("03:15:52", "03:49:17", "04:03:24", "05:30:19", "05:56:49",
    "06:14:04", "09:42:13", "11:57:25", "11:58:02", "12:12:49",
    "15:38:00", "15:44:21", "16:16:04")
    dt <- c(outer(dd,tt,paste))
    xx <- as.xts(seq_along(dt), as.POSIXct(dt))
```

`XX` is the object used to demonstrate what I did, I tried to fix the precession like this

```
xx1 <- as.xts(xx,substr(index(xx),1,16),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Which didn't work, then I added the strftime() function to make the index string before taking the piece I needed.

```
xx1 <- as.xts(xx,substr(strftime(index(xx)),1,16),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

That didn't work either, I still get the full resolution including the seconds part.
What I am trying to achieve is:

```
2014-02-23 03:15    
2014-02-23 03:49   
2014-02-23 04:03
```

Instead of:

```
2014-02-23 03:15:52
2014-02-23 03:49:17 
2014-02-23 04:03:24
```

`align_time` function moves the seconds up to the next second and keeps the precision at seconds still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The underlying type is `POSIXct` which is defined as *fractional seconds since the epoch* so you not only have seconds, but also subseconds -- millis on Windoze, micros on OSs ending in x. So you "cannot get rid of (sub)seconds" but you can look into `round()` which has a method for time objects.
2. Representation is different from display.  Even with subseconds, you can still format, ie display as text, in the format you desire.

And while Roland was filing his commentI was just working on your data to show `round()` and `trunc()`:

```
R> head(round(index(xx), units="mins"))
[1] "2014-02-23 03:16:00 CST" "2014-02-23 03:49:00 CST"
[3] "2014-02-23 04:03:00 CST" "2014-02-23 05:30:00 CST"
[5] "2014-02-23 05:57:00 CST" "2014-02-23 06:14:00 CST"
R> head(trunc(index(xx), units="mins"))
[1] "2014-02-23 03:15:00 CST" "2014-02-23 03:49:00 CST"
[3] "2014-02-23 04:03:00 CST" "2014-02-23 05:30:00 CST"
[5] "2014-02-23 05:56:00 CST" "2014-02-23 06:14:00 CST"
R>
```

Comment: And if you have other reasons for discarding seconds than just displaying data, you can simply use `trunc.POSIXt` like this: `index(xx) <- trunc(index(xx), units="mins")`.

Comment: Yup. Was just preparing that example while you typed it up too.

Comment: my concern with the time including the seconds is:  as you specify more of the "digits" the time period window shrinks.  My current understanding is that if I specified a period from 16:03 to 16:04 the window I am looking at starts at [16:03 through 16:04) the entire 2 minutes.   But 16:03:00 to 16:04:00 ends at the beginning of the 16:04:00.  Thus 16:04:01 for example is not included within that period.  This is the reason behind my effort to remove the seconds.

Comment: @user2004820 I don't follow. `.xts(1:1e4, 1:1e4, tzone="UTC")["1970-01-01 00:01/1970-01-01 00:02"]` returns two minutes. `.xts(1:1e4, 1:1e4, tzone="UTC")["1970-01-01 00:01:00/1970-01-01 00:02:00"]` returns one minute.

Comment: 2014 refers to the entire year, 2014-06 refers to the entire month of June-2014, 2014-06-03 03 refers to the hour 3:00 am of that day, 03:10 refers to an entire minute, and 03:10:00 refers to only one second.  so the difference between 03:10 and 03:10:00 is the first one is one minute while the 2nd is one second.  What I am trying to accomplish is to refer to the entire minute 03:10 not the first second.

Comment: So do `2014-02-23 03:10:00/2014-02-23 03:10:59.999`.  As @GSee and I mentioned, the _underlying variable_ really is of subsecond precision, whether you choose to ignore that for formatting or not.

Comment: Or even `xx["2014-02-23 03:10"]`.  @user2004820 maybe you should show us what you're doing.

Comment: @user2004820 are you trying to format times as character strings to use to subset an `xts`?  Maybe you just need `format(index(xx), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`?

Answer (score 2):

```
strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
#[1] "2014-02-23 03:15:00" "2014-03-12 03:15:00" "2014-05-29 03:15:00" "2014-02-23 03:49:00"
#[5] "2014-03-12 03:49:00" "2014-05-29 03:49:00" "2014-02-23 04:03:00" "2014-03-12 04:03:00"
#[9] "2014-05-29 04:03:00" "2014-02-23 05:30:00" "2014-03-12 05:30:00" "2014-05-29 05:30:00"
```

Comment: I am trying to assess events during the entire minute, my fear is that 03:15:00 refers to the first second only while 03:15 refers to the entire minute.  If I was doing only one calculation I would have tested this and been done with it, but I am using this data to perform different calculations using different R packages.